# How create a table AS SELECT with a serial field

Tags: postgresql, create-table

This query already work.

```
    CREATE TABLE source.road_nodes (
        node_id serial,
        node TEXT
    );

    -- SAVE UNIQUE NODES AND ASIGN ID
    INSERT INTO source.road_nodes (node)
    SELECT DISTINCT  node
    FROM
        (
            (SELECT DISTINCT node_begin AS node
            FROM map.rto)
                UNION
            (SELECT DISTINCT node_end AS node
            FROM map.rto)
        ) as node_pool;
```

Im wondering if there is a way to create the table using

```
CREATE TABLE source.road_nodes AS SELECT ( ... )
```

Instead of having to create the table and then execute insert.

The thing is how create the serial column.

Comment: No, that's not possible. Btw: all those `distinct` operators are useless. `UNION` will already make sure you only get distinct values. `select node_begin from map.rto union select node_end from map.rto` is all you need for the `insert´ statement (and you don't need the parentheses around the select statement for `create table as`)

Comment: Thanks, I put the parenthesis just to show where go the serial field. But you are right regarding the `DISTINCT` forgot about that :$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the table as select:

```
create table source.road_nodes as
select (row_number() over())::int node_id, node::text
from (  
    select node_begin node from map.rto
    union
    select node_end node from map.rto
    ) sub;
```

and the data in the table will be as expected, but the column `node_id` will have no default.

You can, however, manually add the appropriate `default` post factum:

```
create sequence road_nodes_node_id_seq;
select setval('road_nodes_node_id_seq', 
    (select node_id from source.road_nodes order by 1 desc limit 1));
alter table source.road_nodes alter node_id set not null; -- not necessary
alter table source.road_nodes alter node_id set default 
    nextval('road_nodes_node_id_seq'::regclass);
```